# Scroll to load with ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I tried to make scroll to load with update HTML contains using Ajax but I got following errors. If you have some other best method please let me know.

Code:

```
   $(window).scroll(function() {

        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $("footer").height()) {

        $.post("/php/post.php",
        {
            name: "aa",
            city: "bb"
        },
        function(data, status){
            $("#wall").append(data).masonry().masonry('appended', data, true).masonry("reloadItems").masonry("layout");

        });

        }


    });
```

When I use this `$(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $("footer").height()` condition for if condition it is not working sometime it work fist time second time it is not working.

When I use this `$(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $("footer").height()` condition, if i scroll to bottom it is load more than one instantaneously i think this if condition load more than one without updating following condition but logic code it is not.

I want to load one by one when user scroll to bottom of the page footer. When user scroll to bottom of page footer ajax load one HTML contain only and again check if condition again load one contain continuously.

How to solve this problem. If you have best solution more than this please let me know. do you think this https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll is using is better idea without coding.

Comment: I would stick to using the mentioned plugin, why should you write something for which there is already a very decent solution.

Comment: I think you should solve your problem before using plugin. It will improve your skill.

Comment: because if i use only these plugins for every thing in my website it will get more time to load and website size will high something like that. This scroll to load is only have five more line. Why do i use more spaces without coding five lines.

Comment: Could you post your code in a live editor like codepen? It will make we easier to help.